# Isolated (per page) App Part communication

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, iframe

Many of you may know [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/05/14/connected-sharepoint-app-parts-with-signalr.aspx) which explains how to communicate between app parts (from the same provider). Unfortunately the post only describes how to communicate between "all app parts of this provider", e.g. if you have multiple tabs or even multiple browser sessions open (or are even logged in with different users) and are on the same page all app parts on all these open tabs will get notified when a change occurs.

My question is: Does anybody know a solution on how you can isolate this communication to the current-page-session the user is on? This means I only want the communication to be between app parts which are on the currently loaded site (if the site is open in another tab I don't want to communicate with the app parts there).

My issue is, that I don’t know how to recognize which AppParts are on the same page and within 'the same' page request – I would therefore need a unique page-request identifier and a way to pass this identifier to all AppParts to avoid cross-tab / -browser / -user / -session etc. communication.

I thought it may be possible via the `AppManifest.xml` file by adjusting the `Query string` parameters (e.g. pass a Unique-per-Page-ID) - which then would have been passed to the loading URL of the IFrames - but I could not find a parameter which helps me with this.

Has anyone any idea how to do this? Or has anyone done this?

PS: I know you can do it via [PostMessages](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage) but this is not a good solution since you have to place some JavaScript directly on the parent SharePoint page (outside the app part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution which is satisfying for me.

Even though I wrote, that `postMessage` is not what I want to do - this has now become the solution.

I always knew that I can solve this problem with `postMessage` (refer to @Rafael Dabrowski [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/147996/32437) for details).

What I didn't like about it, was always that I thought I would have to edit every single page where I wanted to make use of `postMessage` and add a `JavaScript WebPart` which then acts as a`MessageHub` to receive `postMessages` and then forward them to the iFrames.

However I recently realized that you actually can **inject** JavaScript into the whole web or even site collection (see [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Office-365-Dev/JavaScript-injection-in-SharePoint-Online-Office-365-Developer-Patterns-and-Practices) and [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Scenarios/Core.JavaScriptCustomization)) where your app was installed - you can even do this in an `App Installed Event Receiver` ! This is great because now every SP page is already ready for the postMessage - so it's enough to just place the AppParts on a page and they can start communicating immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of SharePoint or the AppModel this needs to be Addressed with signalR.

A possible solution is this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089386/signalr-push-notifications-to-all-browser-instances-of-single-authenticated-user

You create a subscription Group with the Username, this will dismiss the different user problem. 
Leaves the Tab problem, concatenated with some parameter unique for this tab should solve this, too. But now it becomes tricky. Due to the internet stateless habit each iframe is something like a tab on its own, just embedded in another site. No connection possible when in different (sub)domains.

I see only two options:

- Use some JS on SP Site to deliver some unique parameter to both iframeurls. Unfortunately i do not set any AppUrlTokens which can be used for this in AppManifest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163816.aspx
- Find something both have in common like current time stamp of pageload +/-2 Seconds(a bit obscure, i know)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks - your answer "confirms" what I already know / knew about the topic. For me it's clearly a problem for SP. If SP would offer something like a 'UniquePageLoadID'  as a parameter (which I could then pass via the query string to the iframe) it would be easy.

Comment: i dont think sharepoint officer some thing on its own. you need to use external frameworks/solution via custom development.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i think i stumbled upon a method which might solve the issue: The postMessages API. 
This is nothing SharePoint related but can be used with SharePoint though it features communication between host and iFrame sites. 
So the way to go should be:

1. postMessage the host site
2. return something unique for the page like the __REQUESTDIGEST or something self generated
3. use this as your SubscriptionGroup in AppParts on the site.

This should solve the problem: all the AppParts have the same unique information to differentiate them from other tabs. 
This method is also very good for retrieving information from the host site like querystring parameters for use in AppParts.

A great source how to accomplish this is [this blogpost by Adam Toth](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/use-postmessage-shim-give-sharepoint-client-app-parts-information/)

Comment: Whoops didn't see the postMessage comment. but i find this method seems to be the only way and you do can use the script editor part to point to a scriptfile on your appWeb so you don't have to give up the control over the content of the postMessage.  Or what is your concern with JS in Page? You can see it as a "connected WebPart" to provide some extra functionality.

Comment: The concern is that you would have to add this JS on every single page when you want to use communication between the app parts. And I don't want (and cannot) edit the MasterPage.

Comment: Yes but you put each apppart on every single page so why are 5 clicks more so bothersome?